# python mysql update timestamp

Tags: python, mysql, timestamp

Hi I need help understanding how to update just the timestamp column independent of any column. I've been searching on google for an example of this but I don't see any relevant examples. Below I've pasted code that does it for ID = 1 for testing purposes but there was no update to the time for ID = 1. My goal though is to update the timestamp for all rows regardless of the column name.

*TLATemplate already contains column called 'timestamp'
*config is a module that has imported time

Thank you!

Below is my code:

```
sql = "CREATE TABLE %s like TLAKnoxT5Template" %TLA_dict['TLA_name']
config.cursor.execute(sql)
config.db.commit()
#copy entire table
sql = "INSERT INTO %s SELECT * FROM TLAKnoxT5Template"%TLA_dict['TLA_name']
config.cursor.execute(sql)
config.db.commit()

#update timestamp
sql = "UPDATE %s SET TIMESTAMP = %s WHERE ID = 1"%   
(TLA_dict['TLA_name'],config.time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",/
config.time.localtime(config.time.time())))
config.cursor.execute(sql)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do it without the `WHERE` statement, and quote the timestamp

```
sql = "UPDATE %s SET TIMESTAMP = '%s'" % (TLA_dict['TLA_name'], config.time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", config.time.localtime(config.time.time())))
```

Comment: @user3761743, looks like your timestamp was not quoted, see updated answer

Comment: thank you! Could you please explain what the '%s' means? What is the significance of the single quotes?

Comment: In python, `%s` is the placeholder used in string interpolation like `'hello %s' % ('world',)`. The single quote is needed around the timestamp because mysql require non-numeric values to be surrounded with quotes like `t = '2014-01-01 00:00:00'`.